# Using Com visible .NET assembly on a machine that's different than the development machine

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I am compiling a COM visible .NET assembly on one computer (development machine) and hoping to register it on a different computer (production machine) by using regasm.  To do this I first looked on the production server to see what versions of ADODB is supports.  Then I explicitly reference this version on the development machine in Visual Studio 2010.  I determine that the ADODB is a COM object on the development machine "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" to be specific and import this into my assembly.  It builds without any error.  Then I transfer this assembly to the development machine and attempt to register it.  After running "Regasm /codebase /tlb myassembly.dll"  it gives me the following error:

```
Types registered successfully
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Type library exporter encountered an error while process
ing 'MyAssembly.MyClass.MyMethod(#0), MY_ASSEMBLY'. Error: Type library exporter
cannot load type 'ADODB.Recordset' (error: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could no
t load file or assembly 'Interop.ADODB, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, Public
KeyToken=d699fa88c9ca4dcf' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's ma
nifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT
: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Interop.ADODB, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d699
fa88c9ca4dcf'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\M
icrosoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure lo
gging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fus
ion!EnableLog].
```

Here's the thing.  **1) I'd like to remove my asssembly's dependence on Interop.ADODB.  Interop.ADODB is generated upon adding "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" as a reference**.  I don't see why this is necessary.  It seems Microsoft hasn't considered possibility that some people will want to build on a development machine then transfer to another machine.  **2) Does Microsoft expect developers to install Visual Studio on every machine that requires a custom built assembly?**

If anyone has had a similar experience to mine and were able to solve the issue, can you please share your solution?  Thanks.

Comment: Avoid guessing at version numbers.  Adobdb v6.x dates from an era where it still seemed like a good idea to give these components the same version as Visual Studio.  That was 17 years ago.  Time has not been kind to it and there have been 6 major releases since then.  You should be using version 2.8

Comment: @HansPassant Switching over to version 2.8 seems to have helped.